# Having trouble with node version when running 'npm i'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I am doing a take-home assessment which requires me to 'npm i' a project into vscode and to code a solution. I have downloaded the repo successfully but I keep getting a very extensive error when I try to run 'npm i'.

The instructions say that I should be using Node.js version 14.x. I checked what version of node I have installed and I have node v16.13.1. I assume this should be fine? Or do I need to have the older version 14.x in order to install my dependencies succesfully?

I'm a bit new to coding so hopefully this question makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: A newer version can also cause errors or problems. You should try to install the expected version. You can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your Node.js version

Comment: _"keep getting a very extensive error"_ Well... can we see the error? Please edit your question and include (copy & paste) the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so from my experience, it can also cause errors if you have a version which is newer than the expected version.

To keep track of your node versions, which you have installed I can recommend:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

The first Solution works for linux,mac and wsl, the second is for windows only.